# Why can I not set "Game Window Class" as my class name?

Tags: c++, windows, game-engine, game-development, winmain

I'm wondering why I cannot set the name. This is the error:

[image]

It doesn't even let me assign a char.

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    //create window class
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = "Game Window Class";
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback;//callback
    
    //Register class

    //Create window
}
```

Comment: [What does LPCWSTR stand for and how should it be handled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230758/what-does-lpcwstr-stand-for-and-how-should-it-be-handled-with)

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot convert parameter from 'const char\[20\]' to 'LPCWSTR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481378/cannot-convert-parameter-from-const-char20-to-lpcwstr)

Answer (score 1):

`WNDCLASS::lpszClassName` is an `LPCTSTR` pointer, ie a `const TCHAR*` pointer. `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t` when `UNICODE` is defined, otherwise it maps to `char` instead.

You are compiling your project with `UNICODE` defined, because `lpszClassName` is expecting a wide `const wchar_t*` pointer to a Unicode string, but you are giving it a (decayed) narrow `const char*` pointer to an ANSI string literal instead, hence the error.

You can either:

- undefine `UNICODE` in your project settings.
- prefix the string literal with `L` to make it a Unicode string:

  `window_class.lpszClassName = L"Game Window Class";`
- wrap the string literal in the [`TEXT()` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text):

  `window_class.lpszClassName = TEXT("Game Window Class");`